# deskband can not be modified

Tags: .net, deskband

I have created a deskband followed by the tutorial on codeproject (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx).

After I installed the deskband, I realized there is something need to be modified. So I I uninstalled the deskband, went back to my code and edit the code, rebuild the solution, re-install the deskband. However, in the taskbar, the deskband shows as nothing was changed, the modification does not make any change.
Anyone knows why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you installed a deskband on the taskbar, which means your DLL runs under the explorer.exe process.
The thing is that after you loaded your deskband onto the taskbar - that's it, the DLL is loaded in the process.

For the Deskband really reload the DLL itself (from scratch), you need to restart the process that loads it, meaning you have to restart explorer.exe.

I'm actually working on a similar problem to find a more elegant solution. If I'll find something I'll let you know.

**EDIT :** Check it out: [how can i remove a deskband and delete its dll without restart the explorer process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222711/how-can-i-remove-a-deskband-and-delete-its-dll-without-restart-the-explorer-proc)
It's a similar question, and the answer by Mosc (a hack solution) worked for me.